Does cargo unifies features across [build-dependencies] and [dependencies]?
I have a weird issue in a complex code base and it might come from me not understanding properly how cargo features are being propagated in the presence of [build-dependencies].
So I have a project X that depends on a dependency Y. That crate Y exposes a cargo feature that should never be enabled in the final build.
But the main project X needs the functionality of Y enabled by the feature at build time. So in X I have a [build-dependency] on Y with the feature enabled, and a [dependency] on Y without the feature.
It seems that cargo will only build Y with the feature enabled; it will compile Y with the feature for the build script and will reuse it for the regular dependency. I would have expected cargo to recompile Y without the feature.
What are the details of how features are being unified/propagated across [build-dependencies] and [dependencies]? Reading https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#build-dependencies I only see information about dependencies (not features):

A package itself and its build script are built separately, so their dependencies need not coincide.

Note that this project is using edition = "2021" and resolver = "2".
Thanks for any clarification!

Are you using a workspace and does the root Cargo.toml also include a [package] or is it just [workpace]?

No, crates are not part of a workspace (they are published to an internal cargo registry).

Something to mention is that only the root crate's feature resolver is what matters. The resolver of dependents is ignored.

One last bit of debugging assistance; you can call cargo tree -i dep_Y --edges=features to see what features are enabled by what, in case there's something else in your setup that you've missed.

It depends on the resolver.
With the old resolver (resolver = "1"), Cargo will unify features between build-dependencies and dev-dependencies and your main code. With resolver = "2", however, it won't.
If you have resolver = "2" set and Cargo is still unifying features, this is a bug that you can report.

Is resolver = "2" the default with edition = "2021"? I though so but maybe I'm wrong? I've been adding resolver = "2" for workspaces only, but maybe I should have it everywhere?

@big_gie "edition = "2021" implies resolver = "2"" - source

The main project X depends on Y and requires the feature to not be enabled. But the [build-dependency] is not directly on Y; it is instead on Z which itself depends on Y with the feature explicitly enabled. Could cargo be confused by this setup and use Y with the feature enabled everywhere?

@big_gie For workspaces, no, but for projects yes.

@big_gie I don't believe Cargo will be confused.
